# Raspberry PI4 Benchmark compare to old computer

Tags: arm, benchmarking, intel

my son has the opportunity to have a old computer that will be put to rubbish by his school. He says that the computer (i don't know which one) that works on Windows XP (so quite old) is more powerful than a Raspberry Pi.
I tried to find some benchmark to compare it to intel CPUs but i couldn't find. Is there a place to have some information ?
Sincerely
Olivier

Comment: benchmarks are easy to misunderstand and misuse.  It should be trivial to have a benchmark on the pi that outperforms the windows xp machine, and vice versa.  the pi is quad core the x86 is likely single but there is a wide range of xp machines.  clock speeds are probably similar, the arm is way more efficient than the x86, but the x86 has stuff around it to feed the processor in a way that some programs/tasks would outperform the arm.

Comment: I think a modern linux will make xp look terrible.  Benchmarks are usually subsystem dependant.  Look at phorix